# WordPress with Fullpage.js to include footer

Tags: wordpress, fullpage.js

I don't have a codepen to reproduce this cause it's more of a WordPress issue than a fullpage.js issue.  I have a client that has a WP site and wants to integrate fullpage scrolling on their homepage.  I have successfully integrated fullpage.js into it, and it works as expected (no plugins).  My problem is that I cannot seem to find a way to include the footer.  I have given it the "section" and "fp-auto-height" classes, as the documentation suggests, but it still isn't showing.  I realized that the footer was outside the fullpage div I created, since fullpage.js is only for the front page, so I tried wrapping the `<? get_footer(); ?>` on the front page within the fullpage div, which actually wraps it in the DOM, and the additional styling/divs (that are automatically applied by fullpage.js) were applied to the footer section, however, it still wasn't showing.  Essentially it looked like this:

```
<div id="fullpage">
    <div class="section"></div>
    <div class="section"></div>
    <div class="section"></div>
    <div class="section"></div>

    <? get_footer(); ?>
</div>
```

and within footer.php I have this:

```
<footer class="section fp-auto-height">
    //content
</footer>
```

I realize this is difficult to diagnose without having a codepen to troubleshoot on, but any help/suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: I don't really understand your issue. Can you maybe post the complete generated html ?
Maybe you can make a codepen with the generated html code...
But is the html of footer in the DOM ? if not, where did you put `<? get_footer(); ?>`? In a php file ? (Some host doesn't allow short php tag, so maybe try `<?php`  instead `<? `)

Comment: The generated code is essentially the same as the first codeblock, but instead of the get_footer call, its the footer HTML.  Everything is wrapped in the fullpage id, the footer generates the fullpage.js classes, but it doesn't work on the front end.